# is there any function in opencv that can work on cctv stream

Tags: python, opencv

I'm working on a project to detect age, gender, and emotions from a live video stream using an Hikvision CCTV camera. However, when I run my script, the CCTV stream hangs and gets stuck on the first frame. I'm seeking a solution to this issue.

Here is my code:

```py
import f_Face_info
import cv2
import time
import imutils
import argparse

# Initialize the argument parser
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Face Info")
parser.add_argument('--input', type=str, default='webcam', help="webcam or cctv")
parser.add_argument('--source', type=str, default='0', help="CCTV URL or webcam index (e.g., 0 for the default webcam)")
args = vars(parser.parse_args())

type_input = args['input']
video_source = args['source']

if type_input == 'cctv':
    # ----------------------------- CCTV -----------------------------
    cv2.namedWindow("Face info")
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_source)

    if not cap isOpened():
        print("Error: Could not open video source.")
        exit(1)

    prev_time = time.time()
    frame_count = 0
```

I am trying to get a stream from cctv then my model predcit on the frame but i get stream its is very hang like it take too much time to process 1 frame `

Comment: I don't see `cap.read()` to read first frame. And I don't see `while`-loop to read next frames.

Comment: I used cap.read() and while loop too

Comment: while True:
ret, frame = cap.read()
if not ret:
 print("Error: Could not read frame.")
 break
frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=720)
 Obtain face info from the frame
out = f_Face_info.get_face_info(frame)
 res_img = f_Face_info.bounding_box(out, frame)
 Calculate and display the FPS
frame_count += 1 current_time = time.time()
if current_time - prev_time >= 1:
 fps = frame_count / (current_time - prev_time)
 print(f"FPS: {fps:.2f}")
  frame_count = 0
  prev_time = current_time
 cv2.imshow('Face info', res_img)
if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
           break

Comment: put code in question. It will be more readable. And more people may see it - so more people may help you.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the runtime of your algorithm or processing frame is exceeding the time required to receive the next frame, a situation especially evident when dealing with a camera operating at a frame rate of, for instance, `25 frames per second (fps)` — this translates to a new frame arriving every `1/25th of a second, equivalent to 40 milliseconds (ms)`.

To enhance the performance and fluidity of your application, consider implementing the following techniques:

1. **Frame Dropping**: Conduct a comprehensive time profiling of your algorithm to ascertain the median processing time. Subsequently, based on this metric, you can selectively skip certain frames from the input stream. This tactic is particularly advantageous in scenarios where consecutive frames, for example in video streaming, may be deemed redundant. To calculate the frames per second (fps) for your application, utilize the formula: `1000 / (median time taken by the application in ms)`.
2. **Multi-threading**:

   - **Option 1**: If your application permits, explore the possibility of making it multithreaded. For instance, if you are concurrently performing multiple independent detections, you can distribute these tasks across distinct threads, capitalizing on parallel processing capabilities.
   - **Option 2**: Alternatively, if parallelization at the algorithm level is not feasible, you can still parallelize the frame processing. By leveraging the hardware's thread support, for example, utilizing up to 8 threads if your hardware allows, you can sequentially process each frame on separate threads. Employing shared data structures like [Queues](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html) can be advantageous in orchestrating this parallelism. It's also worthwhile to note that combining both options may yield the most optimized results. Be mindful, however, that this approach is contingent on hardware thread support, available RAM, and processor speed.
3. **GPU Processing**: If GPUs are at your disposal, consider building your OpenCV and Python environment with CUDA support, which necessitates the presence of an NVIDIA graphics card. A multitude of tutorials are accessible to aid in this endeavor, such as [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d8Jx6zO1yw0).

To provide more tailored guidance, it would be immensely beneficial if you could offer insights into your primary codebase, encompassing details regarding the runtime and the nature of individual algorithms being executed. Such information will facilitate the provision of a more customized and effective solution.

Comment: I am using Deep face Library to detect age gender emotion, and race on live CCTV camera

Comment: @MuazzamAli - what is the frame resolution and fps of the CCTV camera? How much RAM is available and what's the max latency/delay your application can tolerate?

Comment: fps=20 , resolution= 3840*2160  12GB ram is available but don't have an GPU it stuck on 1 frame and hang to much

Comment: @MuazzamAli Processing 4K frames in real-time on the CPU is causing system hang-ups, especially during continuous data streaming. To address this, consider your data characteristics for an appropriate strategy:

- High face occupancy: Reduce image resolution.
- Smaller faces: Explore techniques like options 1 or 2 mentioned earlier.

To provide precise advice, sharing a short 1-second video sample would be immensely helpful. This data will enable tailored optimizations to improve real-time processing performance.

Comment: which GPU i need to use for this task?

Comment: @MuazzamAli Deepface uses tensorflow library, so you can install tensorflow-gpu first and then deepface afterward disabling the default installation of tensorflow using pip install deepface --no-deps. For this, better to use Nvidia GPU and then install relevant drivers including CUDA.